# printf не выводит значение

Tags: c, вывод, printf

Возник вопрос, почему `printf( "here it is ",otv2 );`
не выводит ничего, кроме `here it is`. Почему так? И где ошибка?

```
#include <stdio.h>     
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
static double e = 0.0001;//точность


    int amount = 0; 
    double func (double x)
    {
        return cos(x);
    }  
    //метод левых прямоугольников c постоянным шагом
    double LevPrCons(double a, double b, double h)
    { double x = 0; 
      double otv = 0;

    for (x = a; x<b; x+=h)
    {
        otv = (otv+func(x));

    }
      otv*=h;
      return otv;
    }

    //метод левых прямоугольников c автоматическим шагом
    double LevPrAuto(double a, double b)
    { 
        double otv1 = LevPrCons(a,b,b-a);
        double otv2 = LevPrCons(a,b,(b-a)/2);
        amount++;
        if( abs(otv1-otv2) < e*(b-a)/(b-a) )
        {
          printf( "here it is ",otv2 );

          return otv2;
        }
        else 
        {
          printf( "here it is ",LevPrAuto(a,(a+b)/2) + LevPrAuto((a+b)/2,b) );

          return LevPrAuto(a,(a+b)/2) + LevPrAuto((a+b)/2,b);
        }
    }


int main()
{
    static int a = 0; // пределы интегрирования
    static int b = 1;
    static double h = 0.05; //шаг

     LevPrCons(a,b,h);
     LevPrAuto(a,b);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Потому что вы не добавили в строку форматирования ни одного из вариантов "с процентом" и функция логично игнорирует все параметры, кроме первого.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
      printf( "here it is %lf\n ",otv2 );
```

потому как у вас - `double`.

Тут тоже:

```
      printf( "here it is %lf\n",LevPrAuto(a,(a+b)/2) + LevPrAuto((a+b)/2,b) );
```

А еще поясните, что это за хитрость -

```
e*(b-a)/(b-a)
```

Зачем умножать и делить на одно и то же число?...

Ну, и я бы использовал `fabs(otv1-otv2)`.

Comment: чесно, я хз . Просто надо было написать програмку на С, я нашел ее на С++ и переписал.

Answer (score 3):

Из-за отсутствия спецификатора! Это %f для типа double.

Comment: `printf( " here it is = %f ", otv  );` ,добавил, но не сработало.